# Implementing User Accounts into Login System Php

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication, login-control

I want to establish and ENFORCE user permissions on my website.

I have two user groups: buyers and merchants.

For example, for buyers I have (under /login/ dir):

```
<form method="post" action="check_buyer.php" id="LoggingInBuyer">
    <div style="width:265px;margin:0; padding:0; float:left;">
        <label>Username:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
             <span><a href="#">Forgot Username?</span></a>
        </label>
        <br />
        <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="text" name="userName" tabindex="1" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div style="width:265px;margin:0; padding:0; float:right;">
        <label>Password:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <span><a href="#">Forgot Password?</span></a></label>
        <br />
        <input id="UserReg" style="width:250px;" type="password"  name="userPass" tabindex="2" class="required" />
    </div>
    <div class="clearB"> </div>
    <input type="submit" style="width:100px; margin:10px 200px;" id="UserRegSubmit" name="submit" value="Login" tabindex="3" />
</form>
```

**A php script check_buyer.php:**

```
<?php
session_start(); #recall session from index.php where user logged include()

function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return false;
}

require_once('../inc/db/dbc.php');

$connect = mysql_connect($h, $u, $p) or die ("Can't Connect to Database.");
mysql_select_db($db);

$LoginUserName = $_POST['userName'];
$LoginPassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userPass']);
//connect to the database here
$LoginUserName = mysql_real_escape_string($LoginUserName);
$query = "SELECT uID, uUPass, dynamSalt, uUserType FROM User WHERE uUName = '$LoginUserName';";

$result = mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) //no such USER exists
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}
$ifUserExists = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);

function validateUser() {
    $_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
    $_SESSION['uID'] = $uID;
    $_SESSION['uUserType'] = 1; // 1 for buyer - 2 for merchant
}

$dynamSalt = $ifUserExists['dynamSalt'];  #get value of dynamSalt in query above
$SaltyPass = hash('sha512',$dynamSalt.$LoginPassword); #recreate originally created dynamic, unique pass

if($SaltyPass != $ifUserExists['uUPass']) # incorrect PASS
{
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";
}

else {
validateUser();
}
// If User *has not* logged in yet, keep on /login
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>
```

**If a valid user is entered.. it goes to /login/buyer dir**

```
<?php
session_start();
if($_SESSION['uUserType']!=1)
{ 
    echo 'the userid: ' . $userid . '<br>' . 'the type is ' . $userType . '<br>';
    die("You may not view this page. Access denied.");
}

function isLoggedIn()
{
    return (isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid']);
}

//if the user has not logged in
if(!isLoggedIn())
{
    header('Location: index.php');
    die();
}
?>

<?php 
    if($_SESSION['valid'] == 1){
        #echo "<a href='../logout.php'>Logout</a>";
        require_once('buyer_profile.php');
    }
    else{
        echo "<a href='../index.php'>Login</a>";
    }
?>
```

The problem is once logged in as a `buyer`, i can just type in: `login/merchant` and it will take me there, even though the field in the session `$_SESSION['uUserType']` is constantly being re-validated to `= 1`.

How do I stop users from just typing `login/merchant` in the url and they can get access to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**First, you can't stop users form entering a certain url.** The only way to restrict certain scripts or code section to certain users is by code [or, well, certain Apache settings].

This code is wrong, since it (likely) is written to check if a session exists, but it **does not check if it is a BUYER session**:

```
function isLoggedIn()
{
    if(isset($_SESSION['valid']) && $_SESSION['valid'])
        header( 'Location: buyer/' ); # return true if sessions are made and login creds are valid
    echo "Invalid Username and/or Password";  
    return false;
}
```

You need to check `$_SESSION['uUserType']` too.

I'd encapsulate the whole stuff inside of a class:

```
class CUserRole {

  const USER_NO_ROLE  = 'user.noRole';
  const USER_BUYER    = 'user.buyer';
  const USER_MERCHANT = 'user.merchant';

  const PAGE_LOGIN    = 'index.php';


  static 
  public function getCurrentUserRole() {

    if ( ! isset( $_SESSION )) {
       return self::USER_NO_ROLE;
    }

    switch( $_SESSION['uUserType'] ) {
      case 1:
       return self::USER_BUYER;

      case 2:
       return self::USER_MERCHANT;

      default:
        die( 'Inconsistent/Invalid uUserType' );
    }

  }

  static 
  public function forwardIfNotRole( $aRole, $forwardAddress = self::PAGE_LOGIN ) {

    if ( $aRole != self::getCurrentUserRole() ) {

      header( 'Location: ' . forwardAddress );
      exit;

    }

  }

  static 
  public function evaluateCredentials( ) {

    // checks passed login parameters against the DB
    // and sets up the session with appropriate values

  }

}
```

Wherever necessary, add this line at the beginning of your script:

```
CUserRole::forwardIfNotRole( CUserRole::USER_BUYER, 'some/where/address' );
```

Or simply this to forward to index.php:

```
CUserRole::forwardIfNotRole( CUserRole::USER_BUYER );
```

This solution encapsulates the main part of your role management in a separate class.

Finally, I don't see a reason why to set this:

```
$_SESSION['valid'] = 1;
```

Using static methods is a quite simple solution, using the [singleton pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) design would be much better.

Comment: How do I even go about using this?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a

```
session_start();
if( 2!== $_SESSION['uUserType'])
{ 
    ///login/merchant content goes here (login form, whole page, etc.)
} else {
   header("location: http://www.example.com/whatever/buyer_page.php"); 
    //redirect to whatever page you want
    //or instead of header you could do an 
    //echo "You're already logged in" or whatever message you want
}
```

On your merchant pages ? (Every page you don't want buyers to be able to access)

It is important to note that there can be NO html outputted before you use header("location.... this includes whitespace outside of  tags. so make sure there is no whitespace before your opening

Comment: Why should that have anything to do with it though? ONLY 1 form is submitted at a time to login..

Comment: You wrote that calling login/merchant manually is the problem. Therefore the above question-answer is good. JonathonG tells you, that you need to protect the called page login/merchant somehow.

Comment: I must not understand what you are asking for then. If you don't want a buyer to see the login/merchant page, then you would put the code I posted around the content of the login/merchant page, and do a header location redirect if uUserType == 1 ?

Comment: Correct. Better do strict type checking. If you require user to be merchant:  2 !== $_SESSION[ 'uUserType' ]

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, BUYERS when logged in have some their data pulled from the database for their individual account... One of those fields is uUserType , which has a value of 1. Once they enter in valid credentials a username and password... they get redirected to /login/buyer/index.php . MY PROBLEM is, if i login with the dummy credentials I made, it does the login fine.. but then i can just go to /login/merchant and it brings me to the merchant page. I guess I should have rephrased it::

Comment: : how do ONLY allow access to the directories and subdirectories within /login/buyer/ and NOT /login/merchant ??

Comment: You can't deny people the ability to go to /login/merchant, but if you use the code I wrote above on every file that you don't want BUYER users to be able to access, it won't allow them to see anything. in fact, `header("location: http://www.example.com/yourpage");` works SO fast that the users usually won't even notice that they got redirected. the url will just change to whatever you put in there, and the page will change too.